# How to sum up all items in a list of integers while excluding two specific integers?

Tags: python-3.x

I feel like I shouldn't be having so much trouble with this, but nothing I've tried seems to be working.

I need to add up all items in a list of integers (nums) while excluding two specific intergers (a and b).

What I have so far:

```
def suminout(nums, a, b):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] != a and nums[i] != b:
            ??????
    return total
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `return sum(num for num in nums if num not in {a,b})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the number (`nums[i]`) to the total using:

```
total = total + nums[i]
```

Or:

```
total += nums[i]
```

Note that you could use the predefined `sum` function with a comprehension to shorten your code:

```
def suminout(nums, a, b):
    return sum(i for i in nums if i not in [a,b])
```

Answer (score 0):

use a generator comprehension fed to built-in `sum`

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

result = sum(x for x in l if x not in [3,4])

print(result)
```

your function:

```
def suminout(nums, a, b):
   return sum(x for x in nums if x not in [a,b])
```